# how to remove bullet points from tasks rendered by marked.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-marked

i'm using the marked.js library to parse input from a textarea into html .
in markdown a task syntax is written like this : `- [x] done task` or `- [ ] not done task` .

result after parsing :

```html
 <ul>
     <li>
       <input checked="" disabled="" type="checkbox"> 
       done task
     </li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
     <li>
       <input disabled="" type="checkbox"> 
       not yet done task
     </li>
 </ul>
```

i tried to search for a function to override and tweek it to get my desired result , but i didn't understand how the listitem function works .

how do i remove the bullet points only on the task case , but not if i'm parsing a normal ordered/unordered list syntax ?

Comment: are you asking to simply remove the bullets from the li but not other's on the page OR are you asking to remove them based on todo item state? (checked or unchecked)?

Comment: i want remove them from the tasks (normal unordered list items but with a disabled input inside) , i can do it in css , but that's not my goal . i want to override a marked renderer method to do that .

Comment: Did you try removing the `-` from your markdown? Those = a ul in most Markdown parsers. Otherwise, I would suggest the CSS route since you'll get more control overall.

Comment: if i remove the `-` the input gets parsed as a normal text , since in the marked.js spec , a task is a list item . i'll go with css while waiting for someone familiar with marked to answer .

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the original renderer logic in [Marked JS](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/master/src/Renderer.ts) `renderer.ts` and reverse engineered a solution. I also referred to Marked documentation for [overriding the renderer](https://marked.js.org/using_pro#renderer). You have to override the default bullet point renderer:

**Vanilla JS**

```js
const bullet_custom = () => {
    return {
        renderer: {
            listitem(text, is_task, is_checked) {
                /* ORIGINAL: */
                /* return `<li>${text}</li>\n`; */
                
                if (is_task) {
                    return `<p>${text}</p>\n`
                }
                return `<li>${text}</li>\n`;
            }
        }
    };
}

marked.use( bullet_custom() );

console.log(marked(stuff));
```